# Youtube iframe Userlist autoplay

Tags: html, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

How can i `autoplay` and `loop` last video from user?

```
<iframe width="720" height="480" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed?max-results=1&showinfo=0&rel=0&controls=0&autoplay=1&listType=user_uploads&list=DchRussia" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#autoplay) you would need to get the list of user's videos and store the ID of last video, and put it right behind playlist=VIDEO_ID

so your iframe could look like this

```
<iframe width="720" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LAST_VIDEO_ID?rel=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&controls=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=LAST_VIDEO_ID" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```